# How to extract one of multiple matching values from list with priority?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries

```
list_ = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'ABC', 'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'},
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'CDE', 'email': 'cde@gmail.com', 'role': 'Developer'},
    {'id': '3', 'name': 'fgh', 'email': 'fgh@gmail.com', 'role': 'Developer'},
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'CDE', 'email': 'cde@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'},
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'ABC', 'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'role': 'Developer'}
]
```

I am trying to extract a particular `role` from the list which matches the key.

`Developer` has higher priority than `Tester`. If for a particular ID both `Developer` and `Tester` is present then the output should be `Developer`.

However, if the list has `Tester` coming first, then my code won't work, it will give `Tester` instead of `Developer`.

How can I do this correctly? Do I need to put a `break` statement?

```
def find_role(id_, list_):
    role = 'user'
    for each in list_:
        if id_ == each['id'] and each['role'] == 'Developer':
            role = 'Developer'
            return role
        if id_ == each['id'] and each['role'] == 'Tester':
            role = 'Tester'
            return role
    return role
find_role('1', list_)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current script does not assess role priority. Instead it returns the first role from your selected set.

```
def find_role(id_, list_):
    role = 'user'
    for each in list_:
        if id_ == each['id']:
            # check for first role priority
            if each['role'] == 'Developer':
                role = 'Developer'
            # if first role priority has not been assigned, check for next
            elif role != 'Developer' and each['role'] == 'Tester':
                role = 'Tester'
    return role
find_role('1', list_)
```

Comment: why you put elif role != 'Developer'

Comment: i wrote code with `elif role != 'Developer' and each['role'] == 'Tester'` to `elif each['role'] == 'Tester':` my code was not working

Comment: `elif` is used because once the "Developer" role is identified, processing additional conditionals is unnecessary. It slightly improves performance by avoiding unneeded processing. Keep in mind that `role` (tracked value) is not equivalent to `each['role']` (dictionary value).

Answer (score 0):

You can search for 'Tester' firstly until you find 'Developer' role. When you find it you can return that value

```py
def find_role(id_, list_):
    role = 'User'
    for each in list_:
        if id_ == each['id'] and each['role'] == 'Tester':
            role= 'Tester'
        if id_ == each['id'] and each['role'] == 'Developer':
                role = 'Developer'
                return role
    return role
```

Comment: your code wont work if my dictionary is reversed

Comment: it returns 'Developer' and I think this is what you want, If you share reversed list too I can try it on my local